# VScode - regex find match in the middle and remove start and end

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, replace, string-matching, string-substitution

I want to replace all (start and end) of the string but the parameter in the middle (for example `@ModelKey` or `@ProductNumber`) from this Input

```
[MODEL_KEY] = IIF(@ModelKey IS NOT NULL, @ModelKey , [MODEL_KEY]), 
[PRODUCT_NUMBER] = IIF(@ProductNumber IS NOT NULL, @ProductNumber , [PRODUCT_NUMBER]),
```

i need this output

```
@ModelKey
@ProductNumber
```

In [my regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/jMl6Qs/1) this works

```js
(.*)(\@.*)(\sIS)(.*)
```

as expected

1. Group $1 `(.*)` for example `[MODEL_KEY] = IIF(` can be removed
2. Group $2 `(\@.*)` is the group to keep `@ModelKey`
3. Group $3 and $4 `(\sIS)(.*)` are the groups that can be removed

As you can see in this image

[image: Regex replace]

But in vs code the expression `(.*)(\@.*)(\sIS)(.*)` results in an error message:

> Invalid regular expression
>
> Invalid esape

[image: VS-code regex invalid]

#### Question

- Does [visual-studio-code](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-code) uses the same regex syntax as [ecmascript](/questions/tagged/ecmascript)?
- What must be changed to make the regex work in vs-code?

Comment: There's no reason to escape `@` https://regex101.com/r/jMl6Qs/2

Comment: That did it - do you want to change your comment as an answer?

Comment: Who else wants [colored groups in vs-code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/155124)? Give it a thumps up.

Comment: use `(@\w+)` in case there is another `IS` on the line, or `(@.*?)`

Comment: The current regex implementation uses the `v` flag, not `u`, and that makes escaping rules much stricter. More in the original linked answer.

Comment: @surfmuggle glad that solved your problem. I figured there was probably a dupe for this somewhere so no need for an answer